# Passing data to Laravel observer

Tags: php, laravel

I have an observer with method created, but I want to pass additional info that I'm sending through the request that I don't want to store in my Device, only in history. Here's my sample code

```
public function updating(Device $device) {
    $task->device()->create([
        'event' => 'updating',
        'reason_for_update' => ????????
    ]);
}
```

I know I can do it inside Controller, but is it possible through observer?

Answer (score 0):

on the observer try this

```
public function updating(Device $device) {
    $task->device()->create([
        'event' => 'updating',
        'reason_for_update' => request()->reason_for_update
    ]);

}
```